# Table column is too wide

Tags: html, css

My table doesn't reduce enough in width when I adjust the view width. What could be causing this?

I asked a team member if it might be caused by an extremely long String in one of the cells, but he responded saying the length of one string gets wrapped around automatically to a fixed column size.

The cell code is:

```
table .table5-col td.col2 {
    min-width: 155px;
    width: 29%;
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-top: 7px;
    padding-bottom: 8px;
    vertical-align: top;
}
td {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: inherit;
}
```

The parent table code is:

```
table .table5-col {
    min-width: 540px;
    max-width: 945px;
    width: 100%;
}
table {
    display: table;
    border-collapse: separate;
}
```

I THINK that's all the relevant code. There's another parent table to this parent table, but I'm not sure if that's relevant. Thanks in advance.

Edit: I should note that with most data, the table reduces in width just fine.

Edit (example HTML for a cell that might contain a large string):

```
<td class="col2"><span class="font-s color1"><a href="some random link" target="_blank">something something something a+really+long+string+a+really+long+string+a+really+long+string</a></span><br><span class="font-s color2">something something: EUR 799,85 (something)</span></td>
```

Comment: Post your HTML too please. We need a [mcve]

Comment: It's probably because of the very wide text, despite what your colleague said. Please provide an example of that text in HTML.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new at my position and am not sure what I am and am not allowed to post since some data contains user information. I don't know the code for generating the html, but I've posted the html for the cell in question after 'inspecting' the page. Sorry if that doesn't help, but I don't want to be fired haha

Comment: Try `max-width` along with `word-wrap` set these values and play around with then till your happy, and yes your colleague was wrong, so it's your responsibility i.e. some one who knows he is wrong to guide him.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the comments say, your colleague is almost certainly wrong about the very wide text auto-wrapping. In-fact even providing `word-wrap: break-word;` in the `<td>` cell would not be enough, you also need `table-layout: fixed;` in the `<table>` to make `break-word` work.

I don't know exactly what you're trying to do, but [this works](http://scratchpad.io/messy-eyes-6557), i.e.:

```css
table.table5-col td.col2 {
    min-width: 155px;
    width: 29%;
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-top: 7px;
    padding-bottom: 8px;
    vertical-align: top;
}
td {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: inherit;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
table.table5-col {
    min-width: 540px;
    max-width: 945px;
    width: 100%;
}
table {
    display: table;
    border-collapse: separate;
    table-layout: fixed
}
```

```html
<table class="table5-col">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="col2">SomeverylongdatawhichmayormaynotwrapwewillfindoutSomeverylongdatawhichmayormaynotwrapwewillfindoutSomeverylongdatawhichmayormaynotwrapwewillfindoutSomeverylongdatawhichmayormaynotwrapwewillfindoutSomeverylongdatawhichmayormaynotwrapwewillfindoutSomeverylongdatawhichmayormaynotwrapwewillfindoutSomeverylongdatawhichmayormaynotwrapwewillfindout</td>
      <td>Some not-as-long data</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Someverylonlfindout</td>
      <td>Some not-as-long data</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Could you modify your answer to account for nested tables?. The OP's question has indicated that there is some nesting.

Comment: This does seem to solve my problem. Thank you very much!

Comment: I just noticed that adding `table-layout:fixed` results in the cells ignoring the min-width property. Is there a way to add the behavior in your fix without overriding the min-width property?

Answer (score 0):

min-width: 155px; or min-width: 540px;

might cause the problem  - try to play with those values

Comment: The answer box should not be used to post comments (bypass comment restrictions) when you don’t have enough reputation. They are liable to be downvoted, flagged and deleted.

Comment: OK, Thank you - didn't know that